# C - Return value error

Tags: c

How to identify what type of error caused the return value to be -1?

Ex:

```
a = sscanf(ptr, "%s",output);
printf("%d",a);
```

output:

```
-1
```

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation:

`...and errno shall be set to indicate the error`.

Use `perror()` to see what the error is.  Usually, errno is only applicable if there is a read error, which does not apply to sscanf.  -1 is simply returned when there are no match failures or conversions.  Since your fmt string is just '%s', the only reason I can think of to get a -1 return value is if the string pointed to by ptr contains only whitespace.

Comment: The error code will always be `EINVAL` which doesn't really tell you much

Answer (score 1):

You would identify the error by checking the contents of `ptr` and checking that `output` is declared correctly. The typical errors are `ptr` or `output` being `NULL`.

You won't get any more diagnostic information from `sscanf`.